# How to use nats.c library inside iOS/Swift Project?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, nats.io

we are trying to use [nats](https://nats.io/download/swift/) library for iOS/Swift Project. We haven’t gotten a direct swift library to integrate with iOS project. Hence, we are trying to use [nats.c](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.c) library inside our project. We are doing this by generating `static library` out of nats.c project with cmake.

Even though we are able to generate  `.a` file  static library file for iOS architecture, but we are blocked on how to import these headers and link this binary into our project. Using build phases to link binary file into xcode project we tried but it’s not giving us options to create a wrapper around it using swift.

Any help through the **documentation on integrating** or **sample project** or any other way is really appreciated.

Comment: may be this will be helpful -  https://github.com/aus-der-Technik/SwiftyNats

Comment: We tried that already, that is old authentication way. It has no support for JWT, Nkey and Signature way of authentication

Comment: Hi!  Do you solve the problem? I am trying to do the same thing now.

Comment: @Dmitry it's not solved this way. Waste of time. We tried all methods and ended up going with flutter wrapper. Flutter has direct library so we started making wrapper for it and used. Solved the problem

Comment: @SivajeeBattina how you've achieved it with flutter? because I tried wrapping with C but it's failing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a modulemap which points to a static library's headers in order to use them in swift as a module.

I'm writing from my head, so there may be some errors:

example modulemap file:

```
/* MyCModule.modulemap */
module MyCModule {
    header "MyCModule.h"
    export *
}
```

info: As far as remember the header path is relative to the modulemap file - so keep it in mind.

next set the `Import paths` (`SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS`) build setting to point a folder with your modulemap files.

Then you should be able to import the module and use it:

```
import MyCModule
```

Of course you need to embed the library into your project as you would normally do (`Project Settings > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content > +`) and probably need set `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` setting as well.

Be carful using C libraries in swift, you might need to manually  release memory using appropriate functions in order to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a static library project

Then copy whole nats.c library in that project

Than add .modulemap file

```
framework module ProjectName 
{
  umbrella header "ProjectName.h"
  export *

  module * { export * }
  
  explicit module ModuleName
  {
      header "nats.h"
      export *
  }
}
```

In your `ProjectName.h` you need to append this

```
#import <ICNats/nats.h>
```

Then in **Project > Build Phases > Headers** you should move `nats.h`, `status.h`, `version.h` from project to public area.

Then, add that project in your main project workspace, and include the framework in General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

Finally build your project and fix some import path relation issues, as well as some other issues. It's easy, just google that xcode show you and read first stack overflow answer.

After that you can successfully use that library.

IMPORTANT NOTE: that library is not support websocket as transport (at the moment of answer) but successfully support user creds authentication.

Also, here a simple of usage for example:

```
    let pointer_to_url_pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<CChar>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let conn = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let opts = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let sub = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    
    var status: natsStatus = NATS_OK
    
    
    pointer_to_url_pointer.pointee = url_pointer
    logger.log("NATS URL: \(String(cString: pointer_to_url_pointer.pointee!))")

    status = natsOptions_Create(opts)
    if (status != NATS_OK)
    {
        logger.error("NATS Create Optitons: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    }
    

    status = natsOptions_SetMaxReconnect(opts.pointee, 10);
    logger.error("NATS Set Max Reconnect: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    
    status = natsOptions_SetDisconnectedCB(opts.pointee, { _, _ in
        Log.shared.nats.error("NATS DISCONNECTED")
    }, nil)
    logger.error("NATS Set Disconnected Callback: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    status = natsOptions_SetReconnectedCB(opts.pointee, { _,_ in
        Log.shared.nats.error("NATS RECONNECTED")
    }, nil);
    logger.error("NATS Set Reconnected Callback: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    status = natsOptions_SetReconnectWait(opts.pointee, 100);
    logger.error("NATS Reconnect Wait: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    status = natsOptions_SetRetryOnFailedConnect(opts.pointee, true, nil, nil);
    logger.error("NATS Set retry On Failed: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    status = natsOptions_SetServers(opts.pointee, pointer_to_url_pointer, 1)
    logger.error("NATS Set Server URL: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")

    status = natsOptions_SetUserCredentialsFromMemory(opts.pointee, creds_pointer)
    logger.error("NATS Set Credentials: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
    
    status = natsConnection_Connect(conn, opts.pointee)
    logger.error("NATS Connection Status: \(String(cString: natsStatus_GetText(status)!))")
```